# Can't make 'username' attr accessible in User model (Rails 4 - Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I decided after creating a User model through Devise to add a column for a username.  I realized that I'd need to make it accessible so that the database would update correctly when a user submits the new user form.  I then realized that since this is Rails 4 I have to do that through the controller, and Devise doesn't make a controller for my User model available.  So I followed the instructions at the Devise page and created my own custom controller and changed the route to use it.  Here is my custom controller, which I placed in `apps/controllers/users`:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new 
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def edit
    super
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

I then modified `routes.db` with:

`devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }`.

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">
      <%= f.label :username %>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">
      <%= f.label :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">  
      <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">
      <%= f.label :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      Already have an account?  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I copied the `/devise/registrations' views to`/users/registrations` per the instructions at the Devise page.

I'm not getting any errors but for whatever reason when I test the form it writes everything to the database except the username.  I can go into the rails console and create users with usernames but it just won't happen with the form.  My goal is to get the following line of code in `application.html.erb` to work:

`Logged in as <%= current_user.username %>`

But it never works and the failure is reflected in the console, which keeps showing the username as "nil."

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Where is the mistake?? I ran into a similar problem with my Post model with certain things not updating but I was able to fix it by changing which attributes were accessible in PostController.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [registration controller of devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L128), it looks like it is not using `user_params`.  Try changing `user_params` to `sign_up_params`.

Comment: that fixed it!  thanks so much!  I never even thought of looking at the default Devise files on Git.  This will probably help me a lot not just with this problem but with figuring out things in the future.  Thanks again!